# Making a batch mute bot for a voice channel to be accessible only by server admin

Tags: discord

I am an admin for a small group discord server we use for among us. when playing between games we need to batch mute a whole voice channel as a lot of users in the voice channel cannot use push to talk. would it be possible to create a bot to batch mute all users in a voice channel, without affecting other channels (we sometimes have 2 simultaneous games) without having to go in, right-click a user & select server mute?

As a side note, I do not want to use any mute roles as a solution because any new role permissions only come into effect after a user leaves and rejoins a voice channel (which would not be possible for users on phones, needing to stay on the among us app)

I am very new to discord adminning (is that a word?) and have no prior bot experience but if there is any simple bots to add to the server it would help.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is indeed possible. You will first need to narrow down what language you're interested in working with for this bot (I recommend Python, Javascript also works well)

Comment: I'm almost fluent in python so I'd probably choose that. How would you suggest I get started?

Comment: The documentation for Discord.py is extremely good. If you're comfortable with Python, I'd say just jump right into it. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#documentation-contents You can just skip the "Migrating to v1" section because it's not applicable to you. You'll also want to actually make the Bot account: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discord.html

Comment: There are also no shortage of youtube tutorials for Discord.py. I've never seen one I thought did well but they might help you understand the basic structure of a bot script before you start searching the API.

Comment: wonderful, that should help me to get started, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is indeed possible. You will first need to narrow down what
> language you're interested in working with for this bot (I recommend
> Python, Javascript also works well)
> The documentation for Discord.py is extremely good. If you're
> comfortable with Python, I'd say just jump right into it.
> discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#documentation-contents You can
> just skip the "Migrating to v1" section because it's not applicable to
> you. You'll also want to actually make the Bot account:
> discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discord.html
> There are also no shortage of youtube tutorials for Discord.py. I've
> never seen one I thought did well but they might help you understand
> the basic structure of a bot script before you start searching the
> API.

– Allister